# How to get text of link tag by rel content?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get the url in href from :

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://abs.twimg.com/icons/apple-touch-icon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
```

As it points to the twitter favicon.

You can access the website here, it's the Twitter page. To be exact, a tweet url.

https://twitter.com/RichardSocher/status/963117994862768128

There are other links tags in the html,but I need this one.

For the moment I'm collecting all links tags and getting the one in the 10th position (as this is the index of the favicon url):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://twitter.com/RichardSocher/status/963117994862768128'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

#Obtiene el favicon de Twitter
links_list = []
for link in soup.find_all('link'):
    links_list.append(link.get('href'))

links_list[10] #Desired url.
```

Is there a way of getting that 'href' by the link's rel content?

**Edit 1:** It needs to be done by the **rel** attribute not the class.

Comment: what does mean your `link class` ? there's no `class=` attribute in sample link tag

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you're right. It's by the rel attribute.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a dictionary into `soup.find` or `soup.find_all` to match attributes:

```
the_url = soup.find("link",{"rel":"apple-touch-icon"})['href']
```

alternatively, you can use BeautifulSoup's CSS selector syntax and use an attribute match in your selector:

```
the_url = soup.select("[rel='apple-touch-icon']")[0]['href']
```